# Calculating Win Probability given max possible points

Tags: statistics

I am making an app for a series of game nights my friends and I are having, and wanted to add a win probability chart.   The rules are rather simple.   Each person hosts one game night and points are awarded based on where you finish (1st: 4pts, 2nd: 3pts, 3rd: 2pts, 4th: 1pt).   Given that there are four rounds, what would be the best way to track a persons win probability for the whole tournament based on points they have scored thus far.   I dont have a background in statistics and would appreciate any help you can give, thank you!

Comment: Is it a game of skill, or does pure chance determine the order of finish?

Comment: each round is different games of skill.   For calculating the win probability I was only using past finishing order for determining future performance

Comment: thank you so much for responding!

Answer (score 0):

This is the *problem of points* and is generally considered the founding problem of probability theory.  There's a discussion of various methods of solution [here](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Epg2113/index_files/Gorroochurn-Thirteen%20correct%20solutions%20to%20the%20%E2%80%9CProblem%20of%20Points%E2%80%9D%20and%20their%20histories.pdf).  With so few possibilities, I would recommend the approach of Fermat.  Simply list all possible outcomes of the future games and figure out who wins in each.

Calculating the probability of each outcome presents a problem.  You say that the four games are different, but that you want to use the results of the past games to estimate the probabilities that the players will win future games.  If a player is good at one game, does it follow that he's good at another?  I'm dubious.  If they were playing the same game repeatedly, it would make more sense.  There's a discussion of this [here](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Esuri/ccs130a/Bayes.pdf).

I'd be inclined to assume each player is equally to win each future game (or to place second, third or last.)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding!